# java delimiter error

Tags: java, regex, string, delimiter

i want to delimite "/*" in my string:

for example

```
String str="6666 /* 555 / 777 * ttt";

// And result should be
result= 6666 ,  555 / 777 * ttt
```

i wrote the program with

```
String[] line_split=line_str.split("/*");
```

and i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0 *
```

anyone has a solution for me?

Comment: One fairly obvious solution is to google for 'java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near '...

Answer (score 5):

[`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes `Regex` for splitting. And `*` is a meta-character in `Regex` which has special meaning - matches `0 or more` of pattern preceding it.

You need to escape that: -

```
String[] line_split=line_str.split("/\\*");
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message says:

> Dangling meta character '*' near index 0 *

`*` is a regex metacharacter, you need to escape it with `\\`.

---

In such a situation you can use `Pattern` class to build your regex as follows:

```
String regex = Pattern.quote("/*");
System.out.println(regex);
```

The output is

> \Q/*\E

which is your regex.

Answer (score 0):

So yes, it's a meta. But the expression in question, `/*` **is a valid regex**. This actually works, only doesn't give the expected result:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("aoeuaoue".split("/*")));
```

Therofore you have not pasted code that reproduces your problem. But I suppose the real string to replace is something similar, but illegal as a regex.